# Check if the player has hit a margin

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm making a little game using swift, a Snake Game. I've already tried to do this game using python and it worked! To run the game I used a while loop. In this way, I could always change the player position and check if he had hit the margins. Now I have to do this again, but I don't know how to tell to my program to check all the time if the snake has hit the margins or himself.
I should do something like that

```
if player.position.x <= 0 || player.position.x >= self.size.width || player.position.y <= 0 || player.position >= self.size.height{
   death()
}
```

So, if the player position on x or y axis is major than the screen size or minor than 0, call the function "death()".
If I had to do this with python, I'd have just put all this code inside the "main while loop". But with swift there's not a big while I can use... any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using SpriteKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SpriteKit. You can select this when creating a new project, choose Game, and then select SpriteKit. It's Apple's framework to make games. It has what you will need, and is also faster - don't make games in UIKit.

[image: New game project]

Within SpriteKit, you have the `update()` method, as part of `SKScene`. Do NOT use a `while` loop. These are highly unreliable, and the speed of the snake will vary between devices.

[image: SKScene update loop]

Here is a small piece of code to help you get started on the `SKScene`:

```
import SpriteKit


class Scene: SKScene {

    let timeDifference: TimeInterval = 0.5  // The snake will move 2 times per second (1 / timeDifference)
    var lastTime: TimeInterval = 0

    let snakeNode = SKSpriteNode(color: .green, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20))


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if currentTime > lastTime + timeDifference {
            lastTime = currentTime

            // Move snake node (use an SKSpriteNode or SKShapeNode)
        }
    }
}
```

After doing all this, you can finally check if the snake is over some margins or whatever within this `update()` loop. Try to reduce the code within the `update()` loop as much as possible, as it gets run usually at 60 times per second.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed ^ - ^

Comment: @Jacopo Glad it worked :) If you need more help with getting it working if you are struggling, let me know

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate that :) Thx again for your help ^ -^

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly: You are looking for a loop in Swift that does all the calculation and drawing for your game. [Here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html) you have some tutorials about loops in Swift. In fact there are while loops that you could use in order to answer your question. I hope I could help.