# Trying to Use an array for Images that are targets for a game. Making targets appear randomly XCODE

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to get the targets to add and remove from the subview randomly and without adding two to the same spot. I am trying to use an array by appending the imageviews to the array but I don't know how to call the array to make the appear.

```
    func spawnEnemys(){
    let enemy1 = UIImageView (image: nil)
    let enemy2 = UIImageView (image: nil)
    let enemy3 = UIImageView (image: nil)
    let enemy4 = UIImageView (image: nil)

    enemy1.image = UIImage(named: "enemy2.png")
    enemy1.frame = CGRect(x: self.w*0.85, y: self.h*0.035, width: self.w*0.12, height: self.h*0.22)

    enemy2.image = UIImage(named: "enemy3.png")
    enemy2.frame = CGRect(x: self.w*0.85, y:self.h*0.3, width: self.w*0.1, height: self.h*0.18)

    enemy3.image = UIImage(named: "enemy4.png")
    enemy3.frame = CGRect(x: self.w*0.85, y:self.h*0.525, width: self.w*0.1, height: self.h*0.18)

    enemy4.image = UIImage(named: "enemy2.png")
    enemy4.frame = CGRect(x: self.w*0.85, y:self.h*0.75, width: self.w*0.12, height: self.h*0.22)


    enemyArray.append(enemy1)
    enemyArray.append(enemy2)
    enemyArray.append(enemy3)
    enemyArray.append(enemy4)

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3, repeats: true, block: { timer in
        self.view.addSubview(self.enemyArray[Int.random(in: 0...2)])
        }
```

Comment: you are only adding subviews, not removing. maybe thats the issue ? also you are not giving any constraints to your imageView

Comment: sorry the code isn't complete the timer won't even add there's an error I cant add from the array the timer part doesn't work. the error says cant add a uiimageview to subview

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[[UIImageView]]' to expected argument type 'UIView' thats the error

Comment: @HarryFensome - it's not really clear what you are trying to do...  do you want 4 images in a "column", and you want to change the order of the images once every three seconds? Or do you want to show 1 of the 4 images, then hide it and show another one, every three seconds?

Comment: Where are you seeing that error?  If I paste your code into a playground and add some supporting declarations and structure, there's no error.  How have you defined `enemyArray`?

Comment: I still dont know why but it works now just by changing the int from 0-2 to 0-3

Comment: Like with this person at [Check if the player has hit a margin - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59555016/9607863), I recommend you use `SpriteKit` for games.